# Share of success in a binomial process as N goes to infinity

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, binomial-distribution

I have a binomial process with probability of success p. Let k be number of success in when the number of trails is N. I have defined s as the random variable of the share of success $\ s=\frac{k}{N}$

i need to find the limiting distribution of s as $\ \lim_{N\to \infty} s$

I have tried to go about it as follows. The chance of exactly k success is 
$C_k^N *p^k*(1-p)^(N-k)$

Then m=[N*s] where [] is the least integer function.The limit distribution will be the limiting value of $\ \lim_{N\to \infty}C_m^N *p^k*(1-p)^\left(N-m\right) $
I tried to draw some inferences using simulation.It seems that the limiting distribution of the share of success is a normal with mean p [empirical distribution of share of success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4io7.png)

Comment: The central limit theorem shows that the distribution actually is asymptotically normal

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [De Moivre- Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem).

Comment: Hi Peter,what is the mean and variance of that distribtion? Just by eyeballing the distribution,it seems the mean is also p.

Comment: @kangkanDc Yes, this makes sense. In the usual binomial distribution, the variance would be $np(1-p)$, but I am not sure whether we can use this result for this concrete distribution. Unfortunately, I have no idea what the variance is.